# OpenCart: Where is the div for the drop down header cart info?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, shopping-cart, opencart

I am trying to style OpenCart but am having difficulty finding which TPL file holds the div that appears when you click the Shopping Cart icon in the header (the 'mini cart' that slides down - it allows you to view what's in your cart without going to the cart page).

Does anyone know where I can find the .tpl file that has this div (in the default structure template)? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Maybe this would be a more appropriate place for this question: http://forum.opencart.com/

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I've tried there as well.

Comment: Were they able to provide a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, which is why I posted here (I think there's more OpenCart forum activity here)

Comment: Have you used the inspector in Chrome (Firebug in Firefox, or similar) to figure out idetifying information about the DIV (like an id) and then searched the OpenCart repository for instances of this?

Comment: Yes I have - it has the class "content", but there are about 35 .tpl files with many "content" divs

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Why should he try their forums when this is a place for asking questions about OpenCart. Downvote I wish I could on your stupidity

Comment: Exactly. I agree with @PhpMyCoder is bonkers.

Comment: @AlphaApp There are 361 questions about Opencart on SO. There are 60777 on the official Opencart Forum. I wasn't telling him off (I did, if you noticed, provide some steps to try to find the DIV himself), but merely suggesting that he might find more knowledge about Opencart on their forums.

Comment: @MeltingDog....Thank for provide good questions.Make cheer up with us....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why did people downvote you?

The `#content` DIV sits within the `#cart` DIV - you should have searched this.

Open **/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl**

The cart header is in the `echo`

```
<?php echo $cart; ?>
```

To see the code view **/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/cart.tpl** (in version v1.5.3.1)

The section is in the top within **.mini-cart-info** class. Example from some of the code snippet below:

```
<div id="cart">
  <div class="heading">
    <h4><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h4>
    <a><span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></a></div>
  <div class="content">
    <?php if ($products || $vouchers) { ?>
    <div class="mini-cart-info">
      <table>
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td class="image"><?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
            <div>
```

Comment: +1 for the effort and details. True, a good question no need for downvote.

Comment: Thanks guys - yeah I dont know why I was down voted. Maybe because I put PHP as a tag. Thanks heaps for your answers!

Comment: I added those tags but.. this is PHP and it is Drop-Down related. Haters just hate.

Comment: I am curious where is the code that that puts the cart header in the $cart variable for use in header.tpl ? There is nothing in header.php controller that I can find. I figure it's some system wide convention/implementation that a template once rendered is stored in a variable with the same name as the template ?

Comment: Look above. That is inside a module. `view/module/module.tpl' notice that the strings this uses is from `header.php` and also in `header.php` the language files are loaded too.. look at `controller/module/cart.php` too and this is confirmed

Answer (score 1):

I agree With @TheBlackBenzKid.

1) View file can be found with below path

```
"catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/cart.tpl" .
```

2) Controller file can be found with below path

```
"catalog/controller/module/cart.php" .
```

Below link can provide you where to modify the files related to the header drop-down cart. I have give instruction how to modify and created another drop down similar with previous.

Please have a look on this link "https://github.com/pantlavanya/copy-opencart-mini-cart"