# Where is the code responsible for emitting the HTML for the drop-down cart preview?

Tags: opencart

I need to know where the code is that creates the HTML output used for the cart preview drop down, the one that states: you have items(2) in your cart etc. at the top of the page and has the checkout and view cart buttons as well. Also where the javascript for the showing/hiding it is at.

Comment: This was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621864/opencart-where-is-the-div-for-the-drop-down-header-cart-info

Answer (score 0):

The tpl file is:
    catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/cart.tpl

The controller file is:
    catalog/controller/module/cart.php

The language file is:
    catalog/language/english/module/cart.php

the javascript to hide/show it is:
    catalog/view/javascript/common.js

I hope this helps

Please reply if you have any further queries

Regards
Jeremy