# display amount of my account in header of opencart

Tags: opencart

I am trying to display the amount of the account in the header in opencart but im struggling making it work.

This is from transactions.tpl:

`<?php echo $text_total; ?><b> ?php echo $total; ?></b></p>`

I want it in the header for that i try to add this sentence in header.tpl but still doesn't work.

I know i have to modify controllers to but i dont know how to code it.i have been working for quite a while now on it so i would very much appreciate some help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to look at the <?=$cart?> module which brings up the mini cart and then you can basically call variables from that.. see this post for further info too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621864/opencart-where-is-the-div-for-the-drop-down-header-cart-info/11629483#11629483

Comment: Could You please explain *the amount of the account*? Do You mean **total price of products in the cart**?